# Float left TextView and TableLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, position

I want to design something like this :

`[TableLayout 1 Title] TextView1`

`[TableLayout 1]`

`[TableLayout 2 Title] TextView2`

`[TableLayout 2]`

Like in CSS we just use : **Float : left** with setting the width at 100% and everything's fine.

so this is my layout XML code :

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#e9e9e9"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Visitors per Category"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#324A61"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/TableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:stretchColumns="2"
        android:background="@drawable/shape" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="15dp" >

            // Some EditText etc...

        </TableRow>

        //   Separator border
        <View   
            android:id="@+id/firstDivider"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:background="#666" />

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="15dp" >

            // Some textviews etc...

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/EditText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:text="Scans per Gate"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#324A61"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/TableLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="205dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:stretchColumns="2"
        android:background="@drawable/shape" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="15dp" >

            // some textviews etc...

        </TableRow>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/firstDivider"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="#666" />

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="15dp" >

            // Some textViews
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Everything looks fine for me in the code, but graphically I have something like :

`TextView2`

`TextView1`

`TableLayout2` **on the top of** `TableLayout1`

Do you have any idea about this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using linear layout with vertical orientation

```
 <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#e9e9e9"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Visitors per Category"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#324A61"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/TableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:stretchColumns="2"
        android:background="@drawable/shape" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="15dp" >

            // Some EditText etc...

        </TableRow>

        //   Separator border
        <View   
            android:id="@+id/firstDivider"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:background="#666" />

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="15dp" >

            // Some textviews etc...

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/EditText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:text="Scans per Gate"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#324A61"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/TableLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"

        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:stretchColumns="2"
        android:background="@drawable/shape" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="15dp" >



        </TableRow>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/firstDivider"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="#666" />

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="15dp" >


        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This should work

Comment: Wow ! it works perfectly !! That's definitely the good answer!!
 But please may you tell me why did you use the Linear layout ? Thank you.

Comment: If it worked then please [accept_the_answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) .And LinearLayout is used when you want to linearly align your child views inside it by giving orientation as horizontal or vertical. For more info refer to [Layouts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html)